# MYSQL - Select users with most duplicate records with specific user

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, distinct

My table is very simple:

user_id , questionid , answerid (the rest isn't important)

```
id  | user_id  | questionid |  answerid
====+==========+============+=============
  1 |     1    |       1    |  11
  2 |     1    |       2    |  14
  3 |     2    |       1    |  11
  4 |     2    |       2    |  14
  5 |     3    |       1    |  11
  6 |     3    |       2    |  16
```

I need a list of userids who have same answerids as current(specified) userid, sorted from most same answers down.

Basically... list of users who answered same as current user to questions... with number of same answers.

list should look like - for userid(1) :

- userid(2) - 2
- userid(3) - 1

so Userid 2 has 2 same answers as userid 1
and Userid 3 has 1 same answer as userid 1

Thanks much...

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a `left outer join` between all the users and the specified user.  If the join succeeds, then the answer is the same.

```
select qa.user_id, count(qau.id) as SameAnswers
from qa left outer join
     qa qau
     on qau.user_id = XXX and
        qau.questionid = qa.questionid and
        qau.answerid = qa.answerid
group by qa.user_id
order by SameAnswers desc;
```

Note that this measure of the number of same answers is not a very good measure of similarity, unless all users have answered the same questions.

Comment: @HelFrozeOver . . . This answers your question.  My comment is just a judgement on how useful the measure is.

Comment: Is your method better than solution that ended up working for me better:

select A.user_id, count(A.answerid) AS match_cnt from `#__test` as A join (select user_id, answerid from `#__test` where user_id = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($myid).'") as B on (A.answerid = B.answerid AND A.user_id <> B.user_id) group by A.user_id order by match_cnt DESC

Comment: @HelFrozeOver . . . I think the two methods are quite similar.  Yours uses a subquery, which in MySQL incurs the overhead of materializing the results.